# What is 'wresid' in statsmodels library?

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, multiple-regression

To obtain Statmodel summary parameter, I need 'wresid'. I am looking for its explanation and how it helps to calculate other information?

What is the meaning of 'transformed/whitened regressand and regressor(s)'?

Ref: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.wresid.html

Comment: Could you explain the connection between "wrested" and "wresid"? If they are intended to be the same thing, then what explanation does the documentation offer for this?  Is it a parameter of a function?

Comment: That was a typo. I want to exactly know what is 'transformed/whitened regressand and regressor(s)'?